# Entity Framework: how to improve bulk update performance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have some code that does some calculations and based on that it updates a column in one table with a new value. It's fast in the beginning, but over time it takes longer and longer (performance seems to degrade exponentially overtime)

Is there a way to improve performance? By manually specifying what needs to be updated or similar?

(So far my best way to tackle this issue was to create a stored procedure that works as a bulk update, but I'm wondering if there is a native way of doing this in Entity Framework)

My code is something like:

```
public void UpdateValues()
{
    var itemsPerBag = _dbContext.Items
                                .Where(i => i.needsToBeRecalculated)
                                .GroupBy(i => BagId)

    foreach (bag in itemsPerBag)
    {
        CalculateValue(bag); 
    }

    _dbContext.SaveChanges()
}

public void CalculateValue(IEnumerable<Item> bag)
{
    foreach (item in bag)
    {
        item.calculatedValue = CalculateValue(Item);
    }
}
```

It is not literally this, but I'm doing my updated per "group", not doing them one by one, to try to not make a commit too big neither too small.

I have around 850 "bags"/saves and 25000 items. and this is taking 1min to do 11000 updates and 4min to do the 25000 updates.

I think this is a rather small amount of data that should be done much quicker, the calculations I'm doing are very simple.

**EDIT:**

The only way I've managed to improve performance from 4minutes to 20 seconds was to create a stored procedure in the database to update the data, and call it instead of the `SaveChanges()`.

```
private async Task UpdatePlanItems(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
   SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
   param.ParameterName = "@Items";
   param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
   param.Value = GetItemsTable(items);
   param.TypeName = "dbo.ItemUpdateType";

   await _databaseStatement.ExecuteAsync("EXEC dbo.usp_UpdateItemValue {0}", param);
 }

 private DataTable GetItemsTable(IEnumerable<Item> items)
 {
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
       var row = table.NewRow();
       row["ItemId"] = item.ItemId;
       row["Value"] = item.Value;
       table.Rows.Add(row);
     }

     return table;
  }
```

On the database I had to run this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ItemUpdateType] AS TABLE(
              [ItemId] [int] NULL,
              [Value] [int] NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateItemValue]
    (@PlanItems [dbo].ItemUpdateType READONLY) 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET i.Value = s.Value
    FROM [dbo].[Item] i
    INNER JOIN @PlanItems s ON s.PlanItemId = i.PlanItemId
END
```

Comment: it will be better if you can post your C# code.

Comment: Yes, you should post your code, EF Context is not made to do a lot of operations, is made to make just one simple unit of work. You can try with EF extensions which allows direct inserts, or you could throw and recreate your context, bot are simplier than introduce procedure calls

Comment: Ive added some pseud0 code to explain roughly  what i am doing. I wonder is something like AsNoTracking or disable the automatic changes check could help if i would do some of that manually

Comment: Write a stored procedure that does the math and updates the rows in a single set based update statement. It will be dozens or hundreds times faster

Answer (score 1):

You should not save changes after every change and rather do it after doing all the changes (or at least in batches of 100/1000/...) so your code should look like this. Otherwise you're making n db calls (1 per item) instead of just 1 (for all items)

```
public void UpdateValues(){
  var itemsPerBag = _dbContext.Items.Where(i => i.needsToBeRecalculated)
                                 .GroupBy(i => BagId)

  foreach (bag in itemsPerBag){
    CalculateValue(bag);    
  }

  _dbContext.SaveChanges()
}
```

Also having too many changes without commiting to DB (not going in batches) may still be slow especially if you have a lot of dataitems in modified state and you may want to disable [automatic change detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Infrastructure_DbContextConfiguration_AutoDetectChangesEnabled) as it always checks every modified item and rather do the [change detection manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Infrastructure_DbChangeTracker_DetectChanges) at the end. You may also need to re-enable automatic change detection if you're sharing the DbContext instance (which you should not)

```
// Turn off automatic change detection
_dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

// All your operations (calculation/updating/adding items/...)
AllYourUpdatesToItems();

// Manually call detect changes so EF's SaveChanges() actually commits something
_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: the first bit i had done it already it was a problem with my pseudocode.
I did the AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; but performance is the same

Comment: You may want to run performance profiler (part of VS) to see which functions are the ones that run slowly. If the saving bit is the problematic one there is also another configuration that you can set _dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false (it will be validated on SQL side anyway, also if you provide there always correct data validating is just overhead) which can also help you with performance as the validation won't be done by EF.

Comment: that looked promising, but it does not exist in EF core apparently

Comment: Didn't know you're using EF Core (maybe update the title to EF Core as there are some differences), you may want to increase the batch treshold and see if that helps as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating, but not really sure as I did not have to handle EF Core performance yet

Answer (score 1):

EF7 now supports bulk update and delete. [See the details here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7/#bulk-updates-and-deletes)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. You don't need to call save changes after  recalculating each item. It would be enough to call once , after all recalculating is done.

```
var itemsPerBag = _dbContext.Items.Where(i => i.needsToBeRecalculated)
                                 .GroupBy(i => i.BagId).ToArray();

foreach (bag in itemsPerBag) {CalculateValue(bag);}

  _dbContext.SaveChanges()
```